# Combine guava's ImmutableList and varargs

Tags: java, generics, guava, variadic-functions

I want create constructor that will take one or more integers and save it into field as ImmutableList. According to "The right way to use varargs to pass one or more arguments" by Bloch's Item 42 I create smt like

```
class Foo{
    private final ImmutableList<Integer> bar;
    public Foo(Integer first, Integer... other) {
        this.bar = ImmutableList.<Integer>builder()
                .add(first)
                .addAll(Arrays.asList(other))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Why builder doesn't get generic automatically?  And, as it smells. How I can rewrite it?

**upd**
qustion with generics solved. Any suggestions about refactoring are very helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the when calling `builder()` there is no left-hand side of the expression. The compiler cannot infer what type to add there. (It cannot infer it from subsequent method calls)

If you change it to the following, it works:

```
Builder<Integer> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
this.bar = builder.add(first).addAll(Arrays.asList(other)).build();
```

However, you can safely retain your current code - it is fine. And even better than the above example (it's shorter)

About the refactoring - why not use `.add(first).add(other)`? The `add` method has a varargs version.

Answer (score 11):

Regarding your second question (how to refactor you constructor to make it shorter / more readable), I would do this:

```
class Foo{
    private final ImmutableList<Integer> bar;
    public Foo(Integer first, Integer... other) {
        this.bar = ImmutableList.copyOf(Lists.asList(first, other));
    }
}
```

Both [Lists.asList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#asList(E,%20E[])) methods were designed with this goal in mind, according to their javadoc:

> This is useful when a varargs method
>   needs to use a signature such as (Foo
>   firstFoo, Foo... moreFoos), in order
>   to avoid overload ambiguity or to
>   enforce a minimum argument count.

It's also more performant than the ImmutableList.Builder, since it avoids the creation / resizing of a temporary ArrayList inside the Builder.

---